# Temperature and zeta potential

Tags: colloids

What is the temperature effect on zeta potential?

My problem was assigned by my teacher for the final exam preparation: "When the temperature is increased, and given in this temperature range, there is no desorption of potential-determining ions on the surface of colloidal particles occurs, we will have:

A. Zeta potential increases, surface potential decreases

B. Zeta potential and surface potential remain constant

C. Zeta potential decreases, surface potential remains constant

D. Zeta potential and surface potential both increase

***Thought:** It is stated in the below publishment that the zeta potential decreases while temperature is increased at low salinity (0.01M NaCl). The opposite trend could be seen for high salinity (0.5M NaCl).

[Temperature dependence of the zeta potential in intact natural carbonates](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2016GL071151)